# moment js is returning wrong formatted values for an iso timestamp

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm passing `"2018-01-31T22:55:02.907Z"` this timestamp to the `moment()` function but it returns the wrong value after formatting the date part.

`console.log(moment("2018-01-31T22:55:02.907Z").format('YYYY-MM-DD'));`

This should return `2018-01-31` but rather it's returning `2018-02-01`.

It's adding one day to every date like that. I'm suspecting some time zone based issue but I'm not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use .utc when passing timestamp like this:
If you do:

```
console.log(moment("2018-01-31").format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

It would give you the desired result but when passing timestamp like you have done now, what you should do is:

```
console.log(moment.utc("2018-01-31T22:55:02.907Z").format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

You can also see how this works:

```
console.log(moment({ years:2018, months:0, date:31, hours:22, minutes:55, seconds:02, milliseconds:907}).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

For passing timestamp you should check the documentation again.
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/

This also might be a helpful link:
https://coderwall.com/p/exrbag/use-momentjs-to-parse-unix-timestamps

Answer (score 3):

You have to use [`moment.utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/):

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.
>
> If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use `moment.utc()` instead of `moment()`.

```js
console.log(moment("2018-01-31T22:55:02.907Z").format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
console.log(moment.utc("2018-01-31T22:55:02.907Z").format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```